# 300 mb text file using java

Tags: java, nio, text-files

I am a newbie in Java, I want to open a 300 mb text file and read and parse line by line, after doing some research I think nio package is the best way to go. I was wondering if there is anything that I should consider while doing this or any hint from people who have already done this is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're reading it line-by-line it probably doesn't matter what you use.

Comment: So doesn't it make it faster to load the 300 in ram and work on ram or this has extra overhead and I should not do that. Basically I want to do this as fast as possible.

Comment: Sure, operating on data in ram would be faster. Before you said you wanted to read and parse line by line. In any case, read the whole thing into ram then, but use a buffered reader and don't read it line by line. Which io package you use likely doesn't matter enough to worry about.

Comment: Thank. So just to make sure I am in the same page as you I should use something like `BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)` and for size(sz) I should use 300mb?

Comment: @user957314 - no you shouldn't automatically decide to use a monstrous buffer.  That will just tie down a lot of memory to (probably) no useful end.

Answer (score 2):

I was making an index when i came across the same problem.

You can solve this problem by two way ...

1. By using thread to read.
2. By using NIO

Here is the source code of an example with two way in 300 mb file parsing and using.

link >> http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/file-io-old-io-or-nio-which-is-better/

Answer (score 0):

Java NIO will work fine, but so would classes in the `java.io` package.

I'm not sure what convinced you that NIO was needed.

The bigger issue will be what you do with the file once you have it in memory.

Comment: I was just searching about reading large text files with java and i arrived at NIO, looks like since I am reading 1 line at a time it does not matter to use io or nio. Once I have the file in memory, I want to get each line, parsing that line like and making a decision tree based on that line and get a result for that line and go to next line and do the same thing.

Comment: If you can discard the line once it's processed then you shouldn't be holding it in memory. That's the whole point of streaming a file. Of course, don't confuse that with having a buffer of the size of the length of one line; that would be slooooow.